# How to predict a function with a neural network

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, machine-learning, regression, neural-networks, regression-analysis

Suppose we have the following problem that needs to be solved with a convolutional neural network.
We are given an arbirary greyscale image $I(x,y)$ as an input. We want to integrate the image along the horizontal axis ($x$-axis) to get the result as a series of numbers $f(y) = \sum_{x}I(x,y)$. We want our neural network to output $f(y)$.

Many examples of neural networks involve MNIST dataset of handwritten digits, where we deal with 10 different categories (labels), so the last layer will consist of 10 nodes, each for each of the digits. What would the last (or last two) layers be in the context of the problem stated above?

I will restate the problem.

There are many examples of neural networks for MNIST hand-written digits classification problem, where the output is a 10-element softmax-vector with one maximum value corresponding to the prediction. This is the case where a label for a particular data-sampe is just a number (one-element label, that can take values from 0 to 9). Does anyone have an idea how to be able to predict a multi-element label, where the label for a particular data-sample consists of many elements (say, 128)? In other words, how to predict a function? How should I organize last layers to be able to do it? Especially, I would like to have a PyTorch example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The last layer should correspond to one of the possible values of the sum. IMO, computing that sum with a neural net is the worst idea of all times.

Comment: So if the image is of the size 28x28, then the final layer should consist of 28 nodes, each corresponding to the summation for each $y$? Then there will be 28 cost functions comparing the predicted output at each $y$ to the provided value (a.k.a. label)?

Comment: Not at all. What is the range of values taken by $I$ ?

Comment: They are between 0 and 65535, or they can be normalized to the range [0,1]. Why is this important?

Comment: Then you might need 1834980 output neurons. :-)

Comment: This question isn't clear at all. If you know the function $f$ then why not just directly compute it. The only reason to use a NN is that you don't know the function but you know the input/output relationship (for supervised learning).

Comment: @AsAnExerciseProve I gave the problem just as an example, you can think of it as if the function was unknown. The point I wanted to make is how to output a function $f(y)$ instead of 10 categories (in the case of MNIST dataset).

Comment: @YvesDaoust I see your point now :) So how to deal with this nuance, if I want to output a function $f(y)$ instead of 10 categories?

Comment: @CapoPavelMestre: a single output is enough. But again, this is a poor idea.

Comment: @YvesDaoust But one output is a set of 28 numbers representing the function $f(y)$, where $y$ runs from 1 to 28. Should I use 28 output nodes? Mybe instead of logistic loss (or cross-entropy) loss, I should use nother loss-function?

Comment: @CapoPavelMestre: yes one node per row. In fact 28 independent nets.

Comment: @YvesDaoust 28 nets?! Well, if one thinks in terms of a classification problem then it can be understood. But I have a feeling that there has to be a simpler way to realise it using only one network that outputs 28 numbers describing the function $f$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think the solution would be to use a cost-function other than logistic-loss or cross-entropy-loss as they are specifically suitable for classification problems. However, the problem described in the question is more like of a regression type, so other loss function such as mean-squared-error is more suitable. Would you agree?